# Regex in freemarker

Tags: regex, freemarker

I'm new to freemarker. 
eg: a variable named content = "http://www.xyz.com/sites/" . so how to check in ftl

```
        <#if content has "/sites/" in it>
                  do something
        </#if>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and the [`matches`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_matches) freemarker builtin.

```
<#if content?matches(".*/sites/.*")>
   do something
</#if>
```

Comment: Or, `content?contains('/sites/')` is even simpler.

Comment: `matches` won't work though, right? That's an exact match? You'd have to look at the length of returned sub matches.